# .NET (System.Net.Email) - Issues when sending email out

Tags: .net, email, smtp, asp.net-3.5

Experts,

I'm having issue when sending emails out. Currently, I have a feedback form that supposed to send an email to the support email. For whatever reason, I never received any email from the app and the funny thing is when I changed the support email to my gmail, hotmail, or Yahoo account, I received it. The support email is active though.

Is this possibly related to the SMTP setup? Or, is there any possibility that blocks it? Firewall maybe...?? Permission settings??

I'm using Windows Server 2008, ASP.NET 3.5, IIS 7

FYI: I've setup the SMTP settings in the IIS 7. I tried telnet, the same result as what I mentioned above. I didn't get the email in my support email.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it filtered out by a spam filter?

Comment: Did you get an exception when sending the mail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's tough to do email these days.  Most email servers reject mail that doesn't come from properly configured mail servers in an attempt to fight spam, and that includes having correct DNS records, reverse DNS lookup, SPF records, etc...

Even if you have all that, it's quite possible the email is being trapped by a spam filter, or even just rejected by your smtp server.

You need to contact your email servers administrator (the one that receives the email) and find out what policies they have in place to reject email, then make sure you account for those or get the admins to put in an exception for you.

If the email address is internal, just use your companies email server, and don't use the IIS one.

Comment: Found the culprit was that the FDQN was tied up to the machine name by default. I changed it to a valid domain name (e.g. mydomain.com) and things worked properly after that. It doesn't have anything to do with the application..

I started  noticing that the emails got rejected when I got the bounce email and then checked the log.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen Jeff Atwoods [article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html) on this. Shows how tough it is to get this working.